# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Automattic\WooCommerce\Client'

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to Woocomerce Rest API.
I am trying to fetch all products from woocomerce in my new web application in php. But something went wrong from fetching that data. Here is my basic code :-

```
<?php
require_once ('vendor\autoload.php');

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
    'https://www.cotncurls.com',
    '*************************',
    '*************************',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v3'
    ]
);

print_r($woocommerce->get('products'));

?>
```

But its showing me an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Automattic\WooCommerce\Client' not found in ....
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Can you double check the direcory structure and it's included correclty from correct location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error will remain same until we do not use exception class..

```
 <?php


require_once ('..\vendor\autoload.php');

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;


$woocommerce = new Client(
    'https://www.cottncurls.com',
    'ck_****************************************', 
    'cs_****************************************',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v2',
       // 'query_string_auth' => true
    ]
);
print_r($woocommerce->get('products')); ?>
```

Here is the edited code.

Comment: Hey Arvind did the above code worked?

Answer (score 0):

Here in this case I see you are directly requiring the file from URL , i suggest you to download the library from github or run through composer

```
composer require automattic/woocommerce
```

Comment: i have download a library from github and and while using it its shows the me this error.. Fatal error: Uncaught Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException: cURL Error: Could not resolve host: www.cotncurls.com